# how do I access the actual DIV with a jQuery selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div that is dynamically populated with other divs...

```
<div id="wrapper">

</div>

//javascript 
 for(//a bunch of times){
  var d = document.cloneNode('divModel');
  d.foo = {//bunch of stuff };
  document.getChildById('wrapper').appendChild(d) is applied later to fill in child divs
}
```

Now I would like to loop through the children of wrapper and do something with that foo.

When I do it via normal javascript

```
document.getElementById('wrapper').childNodes[x].foo
```

That works as I would expect

However

```
$('#wrapper').each(function (i, element){
      console.log(element.foo); //foo here is undefined
})
```

results in a bunch of undefined

So... I'm guessing that jQuery is actually dealing with some internal wrapper to my divs rather than the divs directly. I'm curious how (or if it's possible) I can access the actual divs in this loop so as to access my custom foo.

**EDIT**
Based on all your answers so far (and thanks very much for the time) I feel like I need to clarify, cause everyone seems to be missing my actual question...
I've modified the code above to be more explicit.

I don't have a syntax error (in my actual code).  jQuery cycles through the wrapper children correctly, it's just not returning the ACTUAL children (divs) it's returning its own version of them, and this custom version doesn't contain my appended foo.

So, what I need is to be able to get back to the actual dom object, not the jQuery wrapper around it. Is this possible?

Comment: `$('#wrapper')` is the correct selector. `#` denotes an `id`. jQuery uses `sizzle` for it's selector, which just leverages `css standards`. You're going to use the same selectors in jQuery (for the most part) that you would use in CSS.

Comment: I'm not sure if the rest of your code is valid, but the CSS selector should be `#wrapper`

Comment: use `$('#wrapper').children().each(`

Comment: getChildById? You mean document.getElementById... Also try element.attr("foo");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right exactly, except the selector is off.  You need `$("#wrapper")`.

```
$("#wrapper").each(function(i,e) { console.log(e.id) });
```

**Edit**

Confirming that it's possible to get an object back from a DOM element ...

```
var c = document.getElementById('container');
var el = document.createElement('div');
el.id = 'new';
el.innerText='the test element';
el.test = { hello: "world" };
c.appendChild(el);
console.log('javascript: ' + document.getElementById('new').test.hello);
$("#container div").each(function(i,e) {
    if (e.test) console.log('jquery: ' + e.test.hello);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eeYHr/3/
​

Comment: I'm doing exactly this. The problem is that when I look into what `e` is, it's not the actual child div, it's a jQuery wrapper around that child div which happens NOT to contain my custom object that's attached to that child div (`foo`). `foo` isn't an attribute so it doesn't turn up in the attr() method response. It's a full on object that I'm attaching to the div when I construct it. So, what I need is to be able to get back to the actual dom object, not the jQuery wrapper around it. Is this possible?

Comment: @Dr.Dredel I just tried a test, appended an element using `document.createElement` and added a JSON object to it.  I could see that object when iterating using `$.each`.  Are you sure something else isn't going on?

Comment: no... not *sure, but I'm not seeing anything wrong as such, in my code... however, if you're sure that $.each exposes the native object and whatever is attached to it, then I guess I must be.

Comment: @Dr.Dredel I'm pretty sure it must be... here's my test:  http://jsfiddle.net/eeYHr/3/

Comment: still not sure what I'm doing differently, but obviously I'm screwing something up... thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the children (and the '#' as mentioned):

```
$('#wrapper').children().each(function (i, element)...
```

Comment: I edited my question to clarify. The problem isn't the loop... it's the missing property.

Answer (score 0):

Some options for you:

```
$('#wrapper').children().each(function (i, element) { ... });

$('#wrapper > *').each(function (i, element) { ... });
```

Answer (score 0):

Or to be more explicit, as you state you are concentrating on child DIVs only:

```
$('#wrapper div').each( function() {
    // do some funky stuff
    alert($(this).attr('id')); // displays element ID
});
```

For further learning, please also refer to this JQuery help page:

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/basic-css-selectors/